# IE8 buttons not working when floating next to an element

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css-float

I'm working on Windows XP with IE8, and I noticed that when I make a button float next to an element, the clickable area of the button reduces to only the area that's not inmediately next to the element. It's little difficult to explain with words, so let's use images. This is the button floating left to the "something" div. Notice where the mouse pointer is:

[image]

Notice the yellow border of the button too. If I do click in this position, the button responds. So far, so good. But, if I move the pointer little upper, the yellow border dissapears, and if I do click, the button doesn't respond:

[image]

In fact, if I click in the colored area, the button doesn't work at all:

[image]

Here is the code (it works in Firefox and Chrome):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input value="Rollover" style="float: left;  height: 40px;  width: 120px;" type="button">      
        <div>Something</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know about this bug? Is there any fix for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try set float left on div something too

Answer (score 0):

You can have your div display as inline-block;

> `<div style="display: inline-block;">Something</div>`

Try it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r48zuvur/)